# Add class to a multiple/specific day in bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm having a hard time in adding a class to a date in bootstrap. Here's the datepicker. [image]

[image]

What I'm trying to achieved is put a small blue dot in the date I specified. I'm thinking of adding a class to the date. How should I do this?

Comment: Which fork of bootstrap are you using?  Can you add the plugin link?

Comment: You must create a circle in the top: 3px; left:3px; position:absolute;
In every day

Comment: @Praveen, I downloaded it to our repository. I don't have any clue what fork of bootstrap I am using.

Comment: @EnriqueQuero, Yeah I know that. But how should I target the specific date I want?

Comment: without knowing what datepicker library your using it is hard to tell.. It would even better if we have a jsfiddle to check it out

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Depending on the datepicker you are using you can do something like this:

Most of the date pickers have a `beforeShowDay` option. You can set a class here to add to the day you want to change.

For this example im using http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker

An example of how to do this can be found here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haxtbh/wnFwS/5/)

You will want to put the dates you want to highlight / mark into an array:

`var active_dates = ["23/5/2014","21/5/2014"];`

Then use the `beforeShowDay` option to check the dates against the current day being shown and then apply a class.

`<input type="text"   id="datepicker" />`

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
     format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight: true,
     beforeShowDay: function(date){
         var d = date;
         var curr_date = d.getDate();
         var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
         var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
         var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year

         if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1){
           return {
              classes: 'activeClass'
           };
         }
      return;
  }
```

});`

The `activeClass` can be any form of CSS. In my example i have just changed the background color. In your example you could offset an image and apply it to the day.

```
.activeClass{
    background: #F00; 
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a date range? I.e. highlight `20-04-2015` to the `24-04-2015`, so it would do 5 days in total.

Comment: When I am using your code its working fine but the today's date is not active

Comment: sorry for previous comment, When I am using your code its working fine but I want get only the event date on selection

Comment: Fiddle does not seem to work, since this answer is old, and the specified days are of 23 may 2014 so you have to traverse in the history inside a calendar

Answer (score 0):

Check beforeshowday:

```
 $('#calendar').datepicker({ 
        calendarWeeks: true, 
        multidate: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
        if (date.getMonth() == (new Date()).getMonth())
           switch (date.getDate()){
           case 4:
              return {
                 tooltip: 'Example tooltip',
                 classes: 'bd'
              };
           case 8:
              return false;
           case 21:
              return "green";
           }
        }
     });
```