# bootstrap3 multiple dates in inline datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

can´t get it to work... I just like to show multiple dates with different colors in my bootstrap 3 calendar. I do not need anything else as it is just a moqup/prototype. I can see the table in firebug and therefor change the "active" day in the css, but can not figure out how / where it´s been created to add more active days and color...

```
<tr>

<td class="cw"></td>
<td class="day"></td>
<td class="day"></td>
<td class="day"></td>
<td class="day"></td>
<td class="day"></td>
<td class="active day"></td>
<td class="day"></td>
</tr>
```

See example picture...
thanks!

[image]

Comment: Working JavaScript snippet or JSFiddle please?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuG6C/872/)

Comment: I don't know but your JSFiddle isn't working maybe because you're using a JS plugin as what I previously experienced on another OP. Anyway to change the color of an `.active` day you can try this CSS: `tr > .active {background-color: #ffff00;}`

Comment: thanks! that is working. unfortunately i can not figure out to have more than one active date on the calendar...

Comment: I can't debug it as your JSFiddle isn't working, you can try to use http://codepen.io/pen/ and make sure that your snippet is fully working, then show us and tell how do you want to create another `.active` day.

Comment: here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGaGGg) . I think it is now fully working. My problem is, that I can not figure out how to make more ".active" dates and in different colors. See example picture above. Maybe there is another solution to make e.g. 07.08.2015-09.08.2015 (green), 15.08.2015 - 19.08.2015(yellow) and 26.08.2015(blue) working... thanks

Comment: I´m just starting with javascript is there someone who can give me a hint?

Comment: A picture in your question is not enough, you need to provide all the source..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could replace your javascript code with the one given below in the fiddle you have added in your comment. It will enable multidate selection.

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: "01-01-1990",
    endDate: "01-01-2050",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    multidate: true
});
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604026/add-class-to-a-multiple-specific-day-in-bootstrap-datepicker )  check this for using multiple colors

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({ 
        calendarWeeks: true, 
        multidate: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
        if (date.getMonth() == (new Date()).getMonth())
           switch (date.getDate()){
           case 4:
              return {
                 tooltip: 'Example tooltip',
                 classes: 'bd'
              };
           case 8:
              return false;
           case 21:
              return "green";
           }
        }
     });
```