# Bootstrap datepicker: how to add class (e.g. "month active") to specific months i want to highlight

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using boostrap datepicker and i want to permanently highlight specific months to look something like this: [example i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5oci.png).

I saw some methods for example beforeShowMonth but i don't really understand how does it work

NOTE: I have datepicker configured to show only months and years

I would really appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604026/add-class-to-a-multiple-specific-day-in-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: i already tried this but somehow i can't modify it to suit my needs (month highlighting)

Comment: What version of datepicker are you using?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap-datepicker.css from http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 var makeMonthActiveForThisYear = false;

        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: "mm-yyyy",
            viewMode: "months",
            minViewMode: "months"
        }).on("show", function (date) {
            if (makeMonthActiveForThisYear) {
                var year = parseInt($(".table-condensed thead tr th:eq(1).datepicker-switch").text().split(" ")[1]);

                var highlightMonth = GetMonthToActive(year)
                
                $('.datepicker-months table tbody tr:first td span.month').each(function () {
                    if ($.inArray($(this).text(), highlightMonth) > -1) {
                        makeMonthActiveForThisYear = false;
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            }

        }).on("changeYear", function (date) {            
            var highlightYear = [2015, 2014];
            var year = date.date.getFullYear();
            if ($.inArray(year, highlightYear) > -1) {
                makeMonthActiveForThisYear = true;
            }
        });

        function GetMonthToActive(year) {

            if (year == 2014)
                return ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"];
            if (year == 2015)
                return ["Jan", "Mar", "Apr"];


        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  <link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.css">



<input type="text" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" />
```

You can do it like below.... this is working and I have tested it before posting but still if you don't get the desired result I will update it with demo.

```
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            endDate: '+0d',
            autoclose: true
        }).on("show", function () {
            var highlightMonth =       ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"];
$('.datepicker-months table tbody tr:first td    span.month').each(function () {                  
      if ($.inArray($(this).text(), highlightMonth) > -1) {
                       $(this).addClass('active');
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: That works great! But i only need one more thing. I would like to have different months highlighted in different years. You think you could do it?

Comment: Yes, even you can do it. :)

Comment: i tried. :D i used changeYear function...but somehow it doesn't want to addClass

Comment: @BlazBegovic Done as your requirement, Happy Codeing

Comment: @BlazBegovic I have changed the code as per your requirement, hope this is what u desired..... Good luck

Comment: It works great! As i desired, with a little bit of twitching of course!. Thanks a lot man!!!