# bootstrap-datepicker beforeShowDay not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have this html element wich has the datepicker (bootstrap-datepicker) (works fine without the beforeShowDays)

```
<input class="form-control text-center"  placeholder="Day" onChange="nice_ajax_3(<?=$_us_id_responsible?>,this.value.toString())"  id="_taho_day" name="_taho_day" ">
```

But, when I try to highlight some specific dates (holidays,etc) It doesn't work, I've tried all date formats (i.e. 'yyyy-mm-dd', 'yyyy/mm/ddd' , 'mm-dd-yyyy', and so on)

Here's the code for the datepicker (some concepts for various answers mixed):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  super_datepicker();
});

var unavailableDates = ["2016-10-10","2016-10-11"];

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" +date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
        return [true,"highlighted day","highlighted day"];
    } else {
        return [true,"highlighted day","highlighted day"];
    }
}

function super_datepicker(){
  // var date1 = new Date(2016, 9, 6);
  // var date2 = new Date(2016, 9, 17);

  // var date1 = "2016-10-12";
  // var date2 = "2016-10-10";

  $("#_taho_day").datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",

    beforeShowDay: unavailable
  });
}
```

Here's the image with the weekends working and datepicker itself (the class that make the weekends blue is "highlighted day" , that's why I try to apply it)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some documentation, or even a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new)?

Comment: I can't figure out how to do in bootply, but, basically is this https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/ with jquery+bootstrap.

Comment: Are you sure that what you are trying to do is even possible with the available options for this plug-in?

Comment: I have this option in the Docs https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html?highlight=beforeshowdays#beforeshowday It's the same as the jquery Datepicker, but does not work ...

Comment: I found the answer here, finally!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604026/add-class-to-a-multiple-specific-day-in-bootstrap-datepicker